# Как включить мои ресурсы в проект

Tags: android, xamarin

**Xamarin android native.**

Все мои изображения имеют следующие свойства : `AndroidResource`, `Не копировать`. Собственно, такие же настройки имеет уже включенный в проект `Icon.png`.

Пытаюсь написать разметку :

```
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Label_iv"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/labels/label" />
```

Начинает ругаться : `No resource found that matches the given name`. Везде просмотрел в проекте указание ресурсов, на примере `Icon.png`, нашел только в `Resource.Designer.cs`

```
    public partial class Drawable
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f020000
        public const int Icon = 2130837504;
        ...
```

Comment: Не знаю, как в ксамарин, а в нативном  андроид папка Drawable не может включать произвольные вложенные папки (без дополнительных настроек скрипта сбрки проекта). Все изображения надходятся только в корневой папке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все оказалось проще :

Свойства у файлов были правильные. То что я копал в сторону `Resource.Designer.cs`, тоже верно. Но как оказалось, **xamarin** сам генерирует данный класс, причем, он генерирует его без вложенных папок, то есть.

Структура моей папки `drawable`, была такой :

```
drawable
|_itemIcons
|_labels
| |_label.png
|_icon.png
```

Все что находится внутри подпапок itemIcons и labels, он не видит... Решение просто : переместить все ресурсы в папку `drawable` и не плодить подпапок.